# Dynamically add rows into a table using data from another table-jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two table on my page like the picture shown here.[image]

What I want to do is:

1. select rows in the Source Table
2. read the data in ID field, Name field from the Source Table, and also the value of radio button.
3. Form these data as rows of Target Table and append these rows into Target Table.

Now Im using two arrays to store the ID and Name that read from Source Table, but im a bit confused about how to form a row for the Target Table.

```
$('#btnLinkCase').click(function (event) {
var caseID = $('#caseID').text();
var linkedIDArr = []; //array list for selected id
var linkedNameArr = []; //array list for selected name
$('#linkCaseTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function (index, el) { //store each paire of <tr> into array
    linkedIDArr.push(el);
});
$('#linkCaseTable tbody tr td:last-child').each(function (index, el) { //store each paire of <tr> into array
    linkedNameArr.push(el);
});
$.each(linkedCaseIDArr, function (index, val) {
    //whats next?
});
});
```

Please see all source code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn5D2/4/)

Any ideas of doing this? Thanks in advance

**Edit**:
If multiple rows are selected they will use the same value from the radio button. eg: two rows are selected and "Type 1" is checked. In target table, their relationship all are "Type 1". I hope I have explained myself..

Comment: Do you only need ID, name and type for target table ? then `var object = [{'name': 'value'}, {'ID': 'value'}, {'type': 'value'}];

Comment: Yes, only need ID, Name and Type. Do you mean store objects into an array? then use the array to form rows for Target Table? can you give me a jsFiddle demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('button').click(function (event) {
    $("#sourceTable tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        var th = $(this);
        console.log("dfg")
        if($(th).find("input[name='link-cbx']").is(":checked")){ //assuming ids are unique remove condition if you do notwant so
            var id = $(th).find("td:eq(1)").text();
            var name = $(th).find("td:eq(7)").text();
            var type = "Type "+$("input[name='linkType']:checked").val();
            if($("#targetTable:contains('"+id+"')").length < 1){            
                $("#targetTable").append("<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+type+"</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn5D2/6/)

Comment: in your code, when select Type 2 the target table will only display Type 1, change the value of type2 to "2"

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works perfectly! and also prevent duplicate IDs in my Target Table.

Comment: @Twocode That because of my html, the value of the 2 radio buttons are all "1", it works fine when i change the 2nd radio button value to "2"